# Can I profile or diagnose slow loading of startup programs in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, ssd, performance

I regularly use both Windows and Linux on similar hardware (with fast SSDs, etc) and notice that the startup programs load much slower in Windows, eg

- MS teams
- Dropbox
- The cisco VPN client
- KeepassXC

In Linux, by the time I'm at my desktop these are usually loaded and ready but in Windows it can be a minute or two before these are loaded.  It even seems to take ages before the first ones even start to load.

[I load these 4 on both systems, though on Windows I also load Onedrive because that client isn't available on linux.]

How can I find out why?

I'm not talking about boot, or any other aspect of starting up because I'm happy with the time it takes me to get to desktop (which on an SSD is actually quite speedy).  Just these things I have set to load at startup (well, most of them set themselves to load, but I'm happy with that).

I know about "autoruns" but I'm less concerned here about disabling these from starting as I am about speeding them up because I *would* like them ready and loaded when I boot.

Comment: Even after Windows starts to show the desktop, it still performs various tasks that leave it *crawling* for some time. Defender may scan key files, an online check may be made for updates, usw. On the other hand, once you see the Linux desktop, the OS is ready for work.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Long initialization times are not normal.  My system typically boot within seconds and I am able to use it a few seconds later.  If it takes awhile then an application is to blame.

Comment: @Ramhound, for the first few minutes, on PC's which Ive used, Windows Defender scans disks. Though CPU usage is not excessive, high disk I/O makes other tasks take much longer to start, This is *not* a third party application.